# How do I get this background image to show on Gmail? (<!--[if gte mso 9]>, not working)

Tags: gmail, background-image, html-email, email-client

```
<table class="row" align="center" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <th class="column mobile-12" width="700" bgcolor="#525252" background="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1P1-AAOYerLtuocs8vcawBpHbozaJ7CcE" style="font-weight: 400; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: cover;">

              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              <v:image src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1P1-AAOYerLtuocs8vcawBpHbozaJ7CcE" style="width:700px;height:500px;" />
              <v:rect fill="true" stroke="false" style="position:absolute;width:700px;height:500px;">
              <v:fill opacity="0">
              <div>
              <![endif]-->

              <div class="spacer" style="font-size: 134px; line-height: 134px; mso-line-height-rule:     exactly;">&nbsp;</div>
              <center>
                <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1x1mI8q21FyheNu1QfddhHyq9RgZm_zxY" target="_blank" class="hover-shrink" style="display: block; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;">
                  <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=12lnl9_m-_LLl8RreCHCn37p4_Ixa89Qp" width="66" alt="Play" style="border: 0; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; max-width: 66px;">
                </a>
              </center>
              <div class="h1" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 60px; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: 3px; line-height: 100%; margin: 30px 0 15px 0; text-align: center;">45bps</div>
              <div style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Grab attention with unique, bold <br> and elegant content.</div>
              <div class="spacer" style="font-size: 135px; line-height: 135px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</div>

              <!--[if gte mso 9]></div></v:fill></v:rect><![endif]-->
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your question to add what you have tried and someone can help you out.

Comment: You are hosting your image on google drive, host it using an FTP (not a free hosting site) and it should show up.

Comment: Try with a <td> instead of <th> where the bgimage is. And place the image in a public server.. eg. use placehold.it for dummy images